# How to differentiate checkbox lists in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to generate a list of cards in flutter with a checkboxlisttile in it so each item can be checked off individually but it's generated so I cant create a set var for each.

```
bool _isChecked = false;
CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(itemNameList[index]),
                  secondary: Icon(itemIconList[index]),
                  subtitle: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('R ${itemPriceList[index]}'),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                        child: Text("x2"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  value: _isChecked,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      if(_isChecked == true){
                        _isChecked = false;
                      }else{
                        _isChecked = true;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

Any tips to make it generate but stay it's own because when clicked it checks all the checkboxlisttiles that is generated at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using one variable to handle the checkability of all items, and when you check and item; it update the variable value, and `setState` update the all items accordingly.

**Solution:** Your approach is much complex. You are creating list of every attribute of an item. One solution is to create an other list of Booleans which handle the checkability. Second solution is create a list of custom model having all the attribute. For example

```
class YourModelName{
  //if your date type is different use that
  String name = ''; 
  String icon = '';
  String price = '';
  bool isChecked = false;
  YourModelName({
    //user @required if you are not using null safety
    required this.name,
    required this.icon,
    required this.price,
    required this.isChecked
  });
}
```

And usage of model list will be as

```
CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(modelsList[index].name),
                  secondary: Icon(modelsList[index].icon),
                  subtitle: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('R ${modelsList[index].price}'),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                        child: Text("x2"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  value: model.isChecked,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      modelsList[index].isChecked = !modelsList[index].isChecked;
                    });
                  },
                )
```